# UITableView not appearing in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uiscrollview

I am combining what was previously two separate views into one unified view inside a `UIScrollView`. One of the subviews I am dealing with is a `UITableView` that is used to display user data in a visually appealing manner.

Here is how I would like the UI to look:

[image: goal layout]

but when I build the app with this view the table disappears. When I move the table further up on the screen though it displays, but with weird dimensions:

[image: display results].

I do not know what is going on here or how to debug it. Has anyone encountered this behavior before and know of a possible resolution?

Comment: Cant say what exact problem is this. If you use autolayout than make sure for proper cinstrains.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! This is a really old application that is still using xib files and springs and struts. It appeared to be an issue when applying the old spring and strut rules to a table view. I was able to get a workaround by embedding the UITableView into a UIView and applying the layout guides to the UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, looks like I solved it. I embedded the UITableView in a UI view and set the layout rules for the UITableView to fill the parent view, and I then applied the layout rules to UIView to position it where I wanted.